# Call Custom MySql Function In Doctrine Query builders Query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, mysql-function

i am having an error while using custom mysql function in doctrine query builders query string.
**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 32: Error: Expected known function, got 'ucfirst'**
mysql function is as below.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `ucfirst`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `ucfirst`(str_value VARCHAR(5000)) RETURNS varchar(5000) CHARSET latin1 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(str_value, 1)),SUBSTRING(str_value, 2));  
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Doctrine query code is as below.

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select("ConcatWs(' ',ucfirst(p.firstName), ucfirst(p.lastName)) as user_name");
$qb->from('Entity\Profile', 'p');
$data = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
print_r($data);exit;
```

any suggestions where i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine stays on top of [DBAL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html) - abstraction layer for database access, its purpose is to hide details of implementation of particular database. [DQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html), query language defined by Doctrine, is also built in a way to remain generic enough. It means that Doctrine is designed in a way to provide unified interface and hence provides no built-in facilities for use some database-specific extensions.

However Doctrine is flexible enough to let you to extend DQL AST and implement required database-specific extensions by yourself. In particular custom DQL function (that needs to be mapped to actual SQL) can be created by implementing own [`FunctionNode`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/AST/Functions/FunctionNode.php) and register it as additional functional node into `EntityManager` [configuration](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php). In your case it will be `$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomStringFunction()`.

Please refer Doctrine [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language) for example of custom function implementation.

Comment: hello, i have created custom doctrine extensions but dont know how to create custom mysql function. can you elaborate it with example ?

Comment: @AmitJoshi this is hard part of Doctrine that requires knowledge of internal representation of DQL AST and related areas. I have no working example and there is little documentation on this topic, you can try to check [this](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html#dql-user-defined-functions) part of documentation for examples.